# how to add In-app Purchases from iMessage app extension for selling Stickes

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I just made a iMessage extension with stickers now I want some Stickes selling to user with in app purchase then whats the problem i am facing , in app purchase is working fine in Main app but getting error when i am using IAP in iMessage extension i.e

```
 Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

Here

```
  - (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
}
```

Anybody can tell the currect Way to add IAP in iMessage Extension for which reason i am getting this error in only Extensions ??

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No, We can't do this. For adding IAP in iMessageExtension we need to create apps in that we can add IAp